# cv2.line not displaying any lines

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, hough-transform

I am trying to detect lines in an image of a Sudoku clip using the Hough Transform. For some reasons which I am not able to figure out, cv2.lines is not displaying the lines in the image. I checked 'lines' in the code below to see if it is empty, but is not. Any help in nudging me in the right direction is much appreciated. The code I am trying to use and the image are given below

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(warp,255,1,1,11,2)
    minLineLength = 100
    maxLineGap = 10
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(thresh,1,np.pi/90,100,minLineLength,maxLinegap)
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in lines[0]:
        cv2.lines(warp,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),3)

    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[This is the image of the Sudoku table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvRV5.jpg)

[The thresholded image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqYJ4.jpg)

Comment: put `cv2.imshow("warp",warp)`  before the waitKey

Comment: @berak Thanks a lot!! That was a noob mistake

Comment: @berak If you can post it as an answer, I would be glad to accept it